# Writing an R package: automatically set environment variables when the package is loaded

Tags: r, r-package

I'm developing an R package, I'd like the behavior of one of my function depends on an Environment Variable `ENV_VAR`, whose default value is `foo`, while users can also change this `ENV_VAR` at runtime using `Sys.setenv(ENV_VAR = 'bar')`. I tried this

```
Sys.setenv(ENV_VAR = 'foo')

#' @export
my_funciton <- function(){
    v <- Sys.getenv(ENV_VAR)
    if (v == 'foo') ... else if (v == 'bar') ...
}
```

but when i build and reload the package in RStudio, I run `Sys.getenv(ENV_VAR)` gives `""`, i.e, when loading the package, it did not set environment `ENV_VAR` as `foo`. Predictably `my_function` also raise error: `Error in Sys.getenv(ENV_VAR) : object 'ENV_VAR' not found`

Comment: Probably you want to look at either `.onLoad` or `.onAttach` (and the corresponding cleanup versions so you can reset things if your package is detached/unloaded).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just as @joran commented, `.onLoad` function is what I need.